# Calculating the volume of the solid bounded by the cylinder $ z = x^2$ and the planes $ z=2-x, y=0,y=2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

My objective should be to find an equation for cross-sectional area and then integrate it over some length, right?

Comment: That will certainly work.

Comment: make some sketch to bettering understand the domain of integration

Comment: Try cross-sections perpendicular to the $y$-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Pojecting the solid onto the $xy$-plane you get $D:-2\leq x\leq 1$ (which is the intersection of the surface $z=x^2$ and the plane $z=2-x$) and $0\leq y\leq 2$. Thus the volume of the solid becomes an iterated integral $$V=\int_{-2}^{1}\int_0^2\int_{x^2}^{2-x}dz~dy~dx.$$ You can proceed after this.

Comment: Your limits appear to be out of order.

Comment: I think you're projecting onto the $xz$-plane.

Comment: $x^2<2-x{}{}{}$